# gitlabでcloneが The remote end hung up unexpectedly, early EOF エラーになる

Tags: gitlab

```
git clone 
Cloning into
Username for '
Password for '
remote: Counting objects: 50195, done.
　remote: Compressing objects: 100% (28896/28896), done.
　fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly6 MiB | 724.00 KiB/s
　fatal: early EOF
　fatal: index-pack failed
```

となり
gitlab.comのおなじ質問から (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/138)

```
unicorn['worker_timeout'] = 60
```

を

```
unicorn['worker_timeout'] = 600
```

に変えたのですがやはり出来ない状態です。
後は何が考えられますでしょうか

Comment: この記事に当てはまるものは無いでしょうか。
http://qiita.com/cacahuatl/items/4d763e98f3934e3569ca

Comment: 「gitlab.comのおなじ質問」へのリンクがあると回答者の参考になるかもしれません

Comment: qiita.comの所の１番、２番は、実際のgitクライアント作業者にやってもらっております。　（私はサーバにインストールした側の人間です）

Answer (score 1):

OP がコメントで言及されていたのですが、 `git gc` で解決したそうです。